# Surface Go Trackpad reset after reattaching

Tags: touchpad, surface

Im using Ubuntu 20.10 on my Surface Go (Also tried POP!_OS by System76 based on Ubuntu) but I've got a issue that bugs me: When I detach the typecover and then reattach it, the trackpad gets reset. It turns off natural scrolling and the Mouse sensitivity gets lowered. After that I always have to go into settings and manually reconfigure my settings. Is there a config file I can edit to make the settings permanent? (I'm not a Linux pro. I can use a terminal though.)